# Add hyperlinks to data validation list (drop-down menu)

Tags: google-sheets

Google Sheets:

I have data validation list in cell A1.The drop down menu has values a,b,c.

I want links to each of them to a specific cell, like user selects "a" from the drop-down and it goes to cell a5, b goes to cell c44 and so on...

**What I need:**
**Scripts that can very fast.

Please please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be something like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = e.source;
  var name = ss.getActiveSheet().getName();
  if (name != 'Sheet1') return;

  var col = e.range.columnStart;
  var row = e.range.rowStart;
  if (col != 1 && row != 1) return;

  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var value = e.value;

  switch (value) {
    case ('Place 1'): sheet.getRange('c1').activate(); break;
    case ('Place 2'): sheet.getRange('c2').activate(); break;
    case ('Place 3'): sheet.getRange('c3').activate(); break;
  }
}
```

Here is the [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TuEkeiVxQzsbEosk4ZNJhgPR__t6gszz5X5zAT6t6C8/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Yuri, it is working like magic. Thanks a lot. But it is slow. Will these two changes in code make it faster? Setting sheet name(Course) and dropdown menu is in fixed cell = C2. Can you add these 2 info and will it take make macro faster? (I mean that "if" can be replaced?

Comment: I don't know how it can be solved with a macro or formula. And I see no way to speed it up significantly. Do you want me to change 'Sheet1' to 'Course' and the 'col' and 'row' checking to '3' ('C') and '2' respectively in my sample of the code? But you can to it by yourself

Comment: I've made the changes in the shared sheet. It works. But the speed is about the same.

Comment: If you want to go faster, you will have to omit script

Comment: And actually it makes sense don't accept my answer if it doesn't solve the main your problem (the speed). Because a few guys will keep to try to answer on already accepted question.

Comment: It looks like @MikeSteelson is one of the die hard guys. Thanks bud. )

Comment: Hi @YuriKhristich ... but your script is something that I will keep. In fact, speed is related to internet latency, not how to write the script. So when user18308583 requests a script, he can't also request speed.

Answer (score 2):

Make a table with choices and cells

try with

```
=iferror(hyperlink("#gid=12345678range="&vlookup(A1,table,2,0), "link to "&vlookup(A1,table,2,0)))
```

where 12345678 is the gid of the sheet and table the list of choices/cells

You will have to click twice but it will go faster to the cell

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this, Mike. Sorry was not well so could not reply. I tried this too. Learning so many things from you. Thanks a ton.